# Winsock2 thread arguments throw exception access violation

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets, pthreads, winsock

I am programming a UDP server-client program with `WinSock2.h`, where the needed arguments (`SOCKET`, `sockaddr_in`) to respective threads are passed to the thread through a struct.

My receive function keeps throwing an exception whenever it gets to the `recvfrom()` part, but only when I'm debugging the program. If I start it without debugger, it doesn't show me any errors nor stops the program running. This exception only happens at the **server**'s side. Also, the `recvfrom()` error checking keeps throwing error 10022 on the client's side, but as far as I understand, this is caused by not having `bind()` on the client side.

Does the server side have the problem with `bind()` being in another function or are my pointers somewhere wrong? I don't have any other ideas why is it only throwing the exception on the server side.

```
typedef struct thread_args {
    struct sockaddr_in sockaddr;
    SOCKET socket;
    int keep_alive_count; 
}THREAD_ARG;

void* receive_packets(void* arguments) {
    THREAD_ARG* args = (THREAD_ARG*)arguments;
    struct sockaddr_in* from;
    char buffer[MAX_FRAGMENTATION + sizeof(HEADER)];
    HEADER* message;

    while (1) {
        memset(buffer, "\0", MAX_FRAGMENTATION + sizeof(HEADER));

        //this is where I get the exception thrown
        if (recvfrom(args->socket, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0, (struct sockaddr*) & from, sizeof(from)) == SOCKET_ERROR) { 
            printf("recvfrom() failed, error code: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            exit(RECVFAIL);
        }

        message = (HEADER*)buffer;
        char flag = message->flags;

        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int client(THREAD_ARG* args) {
    u_short port;
    char ip[50];
    struct sockaddr_in client_sock;
    void* return_value1, *return_value2;

    getchar();

    printf("Please enter the IP address you would like to communicate with:\n");
    gets(IP);

    printf("Please enter the port number you would like to communicate with:\n");
    scanf("%hu", &port);

    client_sock.sin_family = AF_INET;
    client_sock.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(IP);
    client_sock.sin_port = htons(port);

    args->sockaddr = client_sock;

    pthread_t send_thread, receive_thread, keep_alive_thread;

    pthread_create(&send_thread, NULL, send_packets, args);
    pthread_create(&receive_thread, NULL, receive_packets, args);
    pthread_create(&keep_alive_thread, NULL, keep_alive, args);

    pthread_join(send_thread, &return_value1);
    pthread_join(receive_thread, &return_value2);
    pthread_join(keep_alive_thread, NULL);

    return 0;
}

int server(THREAD_ARG* args) {
    u_short port;
    int valid;
    struct sockaddr_in server_sock;
    void* return_value1, * return_value2;

    printf("Please enter the port number you would like to listen on:\n");
    scanf("%hu", &port);

    server_sock.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_sock.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    server_sock.sin_port = htons(port);

    if(bind(args->socket, (struct sockaddr_in*) & server_sock, sizeof(server_sock)) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("Bind failed, error code: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Bind done\n");

    args->sockaddr = server_sock;

    pthread_t receive_thread;
    pthread_create(&receive_thread, NULL, receive_packets, args);
    pthread_join(receive_thread, &return_value2);

}

int main() {
    WSADATA was;
    SOCKET sock;
    char choice;
    THREAD_ARG* args;

    printf("WinSock initialisation.\n");
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsa) != 0) {
        printf("WinSock initialisation failed. Error code: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        return 1;
    }
    printf("WinSock initialised.");

    if ((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)) == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("Couldn't create socket: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    }
    printf("Socket created.\n");

    printf("Would you like to be a server or a client?\n");
    printf("1 - Server\n");
    printf("2 - Client\n");
    printf("0 - Exit\n");

    args = (THREAD_ARG*)malloc(sizeof(THREAD_ARG));
    args->socket = sock;

    switch (choice = getchar())
    {
        case '0':
            return 0;
        case '1':
            server(args);
            break;
        case '2':
            client(args);
            break;
        default:
            printf("Please choose from above\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    struct sockaddr_in* from;
    char buffer[MAX_FRAGMENTATION + sizeof(HEADER)];
    HEADER* message;
```

You have a problem here. You allocate only a `sockaddr_in*`. But you need an actual `sockaddr_in` to hold the address.

```
    while (1) {
         memset(buffer, "\0", MAX_FRAGMENTATION + sizeof(HEADER));
```

Here, the second parameter to `memset` is wrong. It's supposed to be the value to set to, not a pointer to a value.

```
        if (recvfrom(args->socket, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0, (struct sockaddr*) & from, sizeof(from)) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
```

Here, you cast a `struct sockaddr_in **` to a `struct sockaddr *`, throwing away a level of indirection. That doesn't make any sense. And the last parameter, `sizeof(from)` is the size of a *pointer*. That's not right.

```
    THREAD_ARG* args;

    ...

    args = (THREAD_ARG*)malloc(sizeof(THREAD_ARG));
    args->socket = sock;
```

Why this weird indirection? Why not just `THREAD_ARD args;` and get rid of the `malloc` and `->` stuff?

Comment: I see the problem with the `struct sockaddr_in from` now, and I corrected it. If I understand it correctly, the problem with `memset` second argument is that it should be '\0' instead of "\0" ? Also Im not sure, but is the level of indirection with the cast now correct that its `struct sockaddr_in from` and not pointer? The last part with the `THREAD_ARG* args` is because I need it to pass to thread, and the single threads will later update some of the arguments there which needs to be seen by other threads (but I feel like I misunderstood why is it weird)

Comment: @mynael Why do you think any of those things require you to allocate it with `malloc` exactly?